# MuleSoft - Amazon S3 get objcet from bucket's specific folder not the Root

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mule

Hi i have a bucket called `'testBucket1'` and folder in the bucket called `'CFF'`, how to get object from `testBucket1/CFF` not from the root folder `testBucket1`? I was reading the amazon documentation but did not find anything about this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Get object operation, and configure the connector where Bucket Name is '`testBucket1`', and Key is '`CFF/<fileName>.<extension>`'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was trying this now and also before but unfortunately got `The specified key does not exist.` exception

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the hierarchy of folders, along with the bucket name, where the file in S3 is placed?

Comment: It's working now only thing that was causing exceptions was that i did not put the first slash before the CFF `/CFF/<fileName>.<extension>`